# Display Frequently visited documents for the logged in User using Search Results webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, search-query

I want to display frequently visited items (only Documents) by the logged-in user through search results webpart by handling with search query. I have tried using sortby "ViewsRecent" by "Descending" but it is not working. Please let me know where i missed out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the ViewsRecent managed property contains the number of views for an item within the last 14 days.

You can sort by the ViewsLifeTime managed propertyWhen the page is viewed, it will add the count to this ViewsLifeTime field. The SharePoint crawler will pick up the change.

Note: Only when the documents are viewed in the Office Online, they will be recorded.